# Proguard is not obfuscating AAR classes

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, android-proguard

I have been trying to tell proguard to rename classes for anything that is used from aar file.

Let say I have this file defined in the AAR file

```
package com.myweb.lib.common;

import android.graphics.Color;
import java.util.Random;

public class ColorUtil
{
  public static int randomColor()
  {
    Random localRandom = new Random();
    return Color.argb(255, localRandom.nextInt(256), localRandom.nextInt(256), localRandom.nextInt(256));
  }
}
```

**NO Proguard file defined for AAR.**

My proguard rules are defined for the **consumer** app is

```
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
-flattenpackagehierarchy ''

-keep class com.myweb.lib.networkservices.models.** { *; }
-keep class com.myweb.helpmate.http.** { *; }
-keep class android.location.** { *; }
```

The gradle build is like this:

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFile 'proguard-gson.pro'
            proguardFile 'proguard-square-retrofit2.pro'
            proguardFile 'proguard-square-okio.pro'
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
            proguardFile 'proguard-support-v7-appcompat.pro'
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

However, when I decompile, I can see the class as it is.

What I want to achieve is:

- Change the method name
- Change the class name
- Change the variable name
- Possibly Change packages as well

So that it is difficult to link back how, where it is used.

Comment: I am not writing on how to do. But my comment is about why to do. You are creating AAR file, that means you will use this as lib/module into another project. If you change the name of methods/classes/packages then how you will target required class/method into caller application? So I think this is not a good idea to obfuscate AAR file.

Comment: Thanks but I have bold out the text that says I am doing progaurd for consumer app not aar

Answer (score 0):

You can't proguard an aar file that has already been created.  The library module that you or someone else created the aar file with needs to have the proguard configurations setup so it can output a obfuscated aar file under its module-name/build/outputs/aar directory.